# JAX-RS 2.0 Apache CXF client with PoolingClientConnectionManager

Tags: java, jax-rs, httpurlconnection, cxf-client, tomee-7

I am trying to implement JAX-RS 2.0 client using Apache CXF in TomEE-Plus 7.0.2. I am able to connect service using below mentioned code. But I need to implement **Pooling connection manager** and other configuration. I am getting only Jersey client example not Apache CXF example.

Can anybody help me to provide sample example for JAX-RS 2.0 client with Connection pooling with Apache Packages not with Jersey packages?

**Apache cxf client version : 3.1.8**

Jersey client example:

http://www.theotherian.com/2013/08/jersey-client-2.0-httpclient-timeouts-max-connections.html

Sample JAX-RS 2.0 client code:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080/rs");
target = target.path("service").queryParam("a", "avalue");

Invocation.Builder builder = target.request();
Response response = builder.get();
Book book = builder.get(Book.class);
```

Comment: To clarify, connection pooling is a feature of HttpClient and not a part of JAX-RS 2.0.

Comment: I need to use Jax-rs2.0 API with Pooling connection factory. I have mentioned one sample code it does the same but it uses Jersey packages. I need only Apache packages since I am going to use Tomee plus